# Which tree's root can grow the longest?

Tags: botany

In a recent TV documentary it was said that a particular tree root could grow miles long. However, I forgot the name of the tree and I don't remember the name of the TV program as well.

I searched on the internet but I could not get it. Does any one know about this tree and how tall its roots can grow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was it [Pando](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_%28tree%29)? Pando is a single, massive 80,000 year old [*Populus tremuloides*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_tremuloides) (quaking aspen) individual, that is assumed to have a single, massive root system covering 106 acres.

Comment: I suspect it's not.. I heard that the root of this tree can travel many miles

Comment: @Learner Since it was a TV production they would definitely state the total lenght of the root system, just like the blood vessels in a human can reach the moon or something like that. It sounds cooler like that.

Comment: Possibly yes :)